# Does git store the read, write, execute permissions for files?

Tags: git, permissions, file-permissions

I wanted to make some files in git read only. But I couldn't find any good documentation on doing this.

**Does git store the read, write, execute permissions for files?**

Answer (score 44):

According to [kernel.org](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ContentLimitations) git does not store all the permissions possible for files.

> Git is a content tracker, where content is de facto defined as
>   "whatever is relevant to the state of a typical sourcecode tree".
>   Basically, this is just files' data and "executable" attribute.

**So git stores only the content in the file and the execute bit.**

(This is probably a design choice. Probably driven partly by the fact that not all file systems are the same.)

Comment: That's correct. The extra x bit is set in the committed version if any of the execute bits are set on the original, and otherwise not. Nonetheless, the mode of each file is `0644` or `0755`, which *seems* to have provisions for additional bits. A comment in `fsck.c` mentions that some very old repos have files with mode `0664`, i.e., Git did at one point keep group-write permissions. This turned out to be a mistake and was deliberately changed.

Answer (score 3):

`git update-index --chmod=+x foo.sh`