# Updating file permission issue in Git

Tags: git

when I tried to change the permission of the file from 644 to 700 in git, it doesn't take effect. It set the permission to 755 automatically.

**Git config filemode enabled:**

```
core.filemode=true
```

**Git log :**

```
[root@1123 test]# git add .
[root@1123 test]# git commit -m "test"
[master (root-commit) 3111b80] test
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 welcome.sh
[root@1123 test]# 
[root@1123 test]# 
[root@1123 test]# chmod 700 welcome.sh 
[root@1123 test]# git diff
diff --git a/welcome.sh b/welcome.sh
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
[root@1123 test]#
```

Please someone help on this. Thanks.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39666585/1256452 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11230171/1256452 (and note in particular the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230171/git-is-changing-my-files-permissions-when-i-push-to-server#comment46417996_11231682)

Comment: open terminal as admin and try again.

Comment: @ThelittleNaruto actually I'm on root account and doing all such testing operations.