# Force git to commit changes after an attribute update

Tags: git

I'm trying to push changes I made to a file's attributes (read/write permissions, etc.) and git isn't letting me because the actual contents of the file have not changed. Running `git rm` and `git add` on the file did not help, it just says that there's nothing to commit.

Is there a way I can force git to assume a file is changed, or to commit it anyway? I'd rather not make a trivial edit to the file because then the purpose of the commit will seem misleading, even with a message saying so.

I've searched around for other people having this issue and honestly I didn't find any. I don't have a `.gitignore`, there are no assume-unchanged bits set, etc.

Comment: @destoryer I saw that question, my filemode was already set to true. Git still says that there's nothing to commit.

Comment: I don't think Git records read/write permissions, only execute permissions.

Comment: Citing from the linked question: "git really only tracks whether a file is executable or not, not the full set of *nix permissions. So you would have to switch a file between executable/not for it to think you have changed something worth committing".

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666585/does-git-store-the-read-write-execute-permissions-for-files